# Saving .woff2 fonts into html5 filesystem

Tags: html, encoding, fonts, filesystems, woff2

I'm trying to take my entire website offline via the HTML5 FileSystem api. So far, I have has no problems, except for the Roboto.woff2 font that I have gotten from Google's website. Basically I have a blob that writes to a file in persistent storage. However, whenever I try to load the actual page, the console says: Failed to decode downloaded font: filesystem:http://localhost/persistent/fonts/roboto.woff2
1 OTS parsing error: Size of decompressed WOFF 2.0 is set to 0.
When I view the actual file in filesystem:http://localhost/persistent/fonts/, the file size is different as well. I suspect that it has to do with text/plain type. I've tried using application/x-font-woff, application/x-font-woff2, font/woff2, etc, but nothing has worked thus far. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I ended out doing. There are 2 ways.

1. Use charset=x-user-defined when opening the XMLHttpRequest
2. Use xhr2 (XMLHttpRequest with advanced features) and save as a blob. Here's a helpful link: [xhr2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)

Option 2 works on all browsers except Opera Mini.